# Injection and Surjection between arbitrary sets

Tags: functions, set-theory

Let **A**,**B** sets.

We say that **A ≤ B** if there exists an injection **f: A ↦ B**.

We say that **A ≤∗B** if there exists a surjection **f: B ↦ A**.

Provе that:

1. (ZF) for arbitrary sets  **A ≠ ∅** and B holds that: **A ≤ B ⇒ A ≤ ∗B**;
2. (ZF) for arbitrary **A** and **B**, if **B** is well ordered, then: **A ≤ ∗ B ⇒ A ≤ B**;

Proof:

1. **A ≤ B** is equivalent to: there is an injection **f: A ↦ B**, namely if  (for arbitrary $a,b \in A \& f(a)=f(b)⇒a=b$), but this means that (∃f(a)∃f(b) & f(a),f(b)∈B)⇒there exists a map for elements a and b onto f(a) and f(b), but since arbitrary a,b ⇒(∀a∈A)(∃f(a)∈B).

2.Since B is well ordered, then in any non-empty subset S⊆B, there is such an element s≤b for all b∈S. We are given A ≤ ∗ B  which is equivalent to: there exists a surjection g:B ↦ A which for arbitrary b∈B returns f(b)∈A and if min(b) in regard to ≤, then f(b)=b ∈A (this is actualy when A=B). Now if we suppose that for arbitray m,n∈A(m≠n) we have g(m)=g(n) ∈ B, where g is a function A↦B. Now if we apply f(g(m)) and f(g(n)), we have 2 cases.
First:min( f(g(m)) ) and min( f(g(n)) )⇒ f(g(m))=g(m)=g(n)=f(g(n)) ⇒ f is an injection-Absurd.
Second:min( f(g(m)) )⇒ f(g(m))=g(m)=g(n)≠f(g(n)) .

If someone have the time to help me, I will be thankful.

Comment: Where do you have these definitions from? Usually $\leq^*$ is defined to explicitly include the case where $A=\varnothing$ (since there's no surjection in that case).

Comment: @AsafKaragila Hello, this definitions are used with this meaning concretely in the problem. They are given as an exercise in a booklet, without any further explanations, that is the reason why I need help.

Comment: Go and tell whomever gave that exercise booklet that I said that the definition of $\leq^*$ should be modified. Then, it would be helpful to you in general to learn some $\rm\LaTeX$, and by extension to learn how to use MathJax on this site.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Alright, I will try to get further information about the usage of this symbol, then hopefully it will be more understandable.